# I have tried customizing exoplayer, Will it be a violation of google policy?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, google-play, exoplayer

I have tried to customize Exoplayer in android studio for the fullscreen button, volume control then it will be a violation of `Google policy`? I attached a sample image, like this - Please guide us. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't violate Google's policy. Exoplayer is an open-source player and the docs state "ExoPlayer is easy to customize and extend". This is the purpose, to provide basic support for video playback and allow you to customize the experience.

Check out these resources:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

https://exoplayer.dev/

Comment: My developer had told me, we can't more modify or customize exoplayer because of google policy, so that's why confirmed this. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Richard I wanted to know if how the playerview can be hidden when streaming audio with no artwork...I want to hide the black screen or have it wrap around the controls